Kotlin. How to collect a number in Float format from four UBytes?
Kotlin. There is a packet with received data, byte by byte, located in the array var packet = Array<UByte>(20) How to tell the compiler that the bytes packet[2], packet[3], packet[4] and packet[5] are one number in the format Float? To assign it to var X: Float =
In C this is done using pointers. I'm new to Kotlin.
